# Flutter Web not displaying Material Design Icons

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-web

I started `Flutter web` and i wanted to add Material icons to my Flutter web app but its displaying boxes instead.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It isnt an error. It is a limitation of flutter web

Comment: But in the samples, icons were showing

Comment: This looks like it might be an issue with the the fonts? Your index.html or FontManifest might be missing the material icons

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [flutter_web repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/tree/master/examples/gallery/web/assets):

*Note: a reference to `MaterialIcons` is intentionally omitted because the corresponding font is not included in this source.*

*If you add `MaterialIcons-Extended.ttf` to this directory, you can update `FontManifest.json` as follows:*

```
[
  {
    "family": "MaterialIcons",
    "fonts": [
      {
        "asset": "MaterialIcons-Extended.ttf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "family": "GoogleSans",
    "fonts": [
      {
        "asset": "GoogleSans-Regular.ttf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "family": "GalleryIcons",
    "fonts": [
      {
        "asset": "GalleryIcons.ttf"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Solution/Workaround**

Download `MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf` [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf), put it inside your `assets` folder and update your `FontManifest.json` accordingly.

Comment: your JSON code says `MaterialIcons-Extended.ttf` but you gave link to `MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf`. please edit

Comment: @JideGuru the JSON is from repo, and below is my alternative solution since I can't find `MaterialIcons-Extended.ttf`. Will update once I get the actual font.

Comment: Putting `"asset": "MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf"` into the JSON file works for me.

Comment: @Zerocchi I can't update FontManifest.json file, because I deploy web flutter directly via azure pipeline. So you have any solutions else?

Comment: link of material icon is updated : 
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/font/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf

Answer (score 10):

[According to this](https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/web/charts/example/web/assets/FontManifest.json)
you can directly add Material icons to `FontManifest.json` as shown below.

```
[
  {
    "family": "MaterialIcons",
    "fonts": [
      {
        "asset": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v42/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: If you prefer to have the file for the font and not the web reference, you can open the [link](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v42/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) (that is the one posted in the answer above) in the browser, download the file and change the extension to .ttf .
In my project, it works also in this way.
In this case, in your FontManfest.json you can use the same references as the answer, but writing the asset property like this:

"asset": "fonts/MaterialIcons-Extended.ttf"

Answer (score 1):

this solved my problem: after building web output, look in the folder build/web/assets/fonts. if There is a file named: MaterialIcons-Regular.**otf** then add this to pubspec.yaml:

```
- family: MaterialIcons
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf
```

and the FontManifest.json (in the path web/assets/FontManifest.json):

```
{
"family": "MaterialIcons",
"fonts": [
  {
    "asset": "fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf"
  }
]
```

}

pay attention to the format of the font file. it is **otf** not ttf

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have discovered about this problem. I hope it helps somebody. If you add the font to the `web/assets/fontManifest.json` file and then run `flutter build web`, a new manifest overwrites the one you just edited (without the font). Then, when you deploy, you don't get your icons.

I made a copy of the manifest and added it to the `build/web/assets` folder after running `flutter build web`. Note, this is where I am building and deploying from for Firebase hosting. The font should also be in the `build/web/assets/fonts` folder. When you deploy, it should all get uploaded and your font will work.

Be aware that you will need to manually swap out the manifest after the `flutter build web` command for this to work for every deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure

```
uses-material-design: true
```

is present in `pubspec.yaml` parallel to assets / images

Comment: This should work - but it does not for me

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the files to the server, make sure that the 'assets' folder is also uploaded. Because while the files are uploaded to the server in bulk, the ones in the form of folders are not uploaded, you should upload them separately.

Answer (score 0):

In my project the font family was defined in pubspec.yaml without capitals, but I referenced it in my code starting with a capital.

This was no problem as long as I was testing on Android: the icons showed up anyway. But apparently it does make a difference when compiling for web. Hence the icons were not shown there.

Because of problems with icons fonts on older versions of flutter mentioned all over the web I was completely on the wrong track here :-)